# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to deserialize a very complex JSON in Dart, however I do not know what's wrong.

Once it tried to deserialize, it showed me this error: "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast"

Does anyone know what's going on?

Here's my code:

### Json

```
{
  "Instytucja": [
    "TypInstytucji": "bank krajowy",
      "PodtypInstytucji": "bank centralny",
      "NrInstytucji": 101,
      "NazwaInstytucji": "Narodowy Bank Polski",
      "SymbolLiterowy": "NBP",
      "DataRozpDzial": "1945-01-15",
      "NIP": 5250008198,
      "IdentyfikatorLEI": "549300K7Z2KT76WQJD18",
      "WWW": "www.nbp.pl",
        "Jendostka": [
        {
          "NrEwidencyjny": "A000001",
          "TypJednostki": "Centrala",
          "NazwaJednostki": "Centrala",
          "SymbolLiterowy": "C-la",
          "DaneAdresowe": {
            "kraj": "POLSKA",
            "wojewodztwo": "MAZOWIECKIE",
            "powiat": "Warszawa",
            "miejscowosc": "Warszawa",
            "ulica": "ul. Świętokrzyska",
            "numerBudynku": "11/21",
            "kodPocztowy": "00-919",
            "poczta": "Warszawa",
            "nrSkrytkiPocztowej": 1011
          },
          "DataPodjeciaDzialalnosci": "1945-01-15",
          "NumerTelefonu": "22 185 10 10",
          "NumerFaksu": "22 185 23 09",
          "NumerRozliczeniowy": [
            {
              "NrRozliczeniowy": 10100000,
              "NazwaNumeru": "Centrala",
              "KodyBIC": [
                "BIC NBPLPLPWXXX",
                "BIC SEPA NBPLPLPWXXX"
              ],
              "DataWygenerowania": "1945-01-15"
            },
            {
              "NrRozliczeniowy": 10100055,
              "NazwaNumeru": "Centrala - B2B Collect",
              "KodyBIC": [
                "BIC NBPLPLPWXXX",
                "BIC SEPA NBPLPLPWXXX"
              ],
              "DataWygenerowania": "2008-04-01"
            },
            {
              "NrRozliczeniowy": 10100068,
              "NazwaNumeru": "Centrala - NBPCollect",
              "KodyBIC": [
                "BIC NBPLPLPWXXX",
                "BIC SEPA NBPLPLPWXXX"
              ],
              "DataWygenerowania": "2008-10-01"
            },
            {
              "NrRozliczeniowy": 10100071,
              "NazwaNumeru": "Centrala - B2B-2",
              "KodyBIC": [
                "BIC NBPLPLPWXXX",
                "BIC SEPA NBPLPLPWXXX"
              ],
              "DataWygenerowania": "2016-08-01"
            }
          ]
        },
  ]
 ]
}
```

### Entity

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

abstract class Bank extends Equatable {
  List<Institution> get institutions;
}

abstract class Institution extends Equatable {
  List<Unit> get units;
}

abstract class Unit extends Equatable {
  List<SortNumber> get sortNumbers;
}

abstract class SortNumber extends Equatable {
  int get sortNumber;
}
```

### Model

```
import 'package:jaki_to_bank/features/home/domain/entities/bank.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'bank_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class BankModel extends Bank {
  BankModel({required this.institutions});

  factory BankModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BankModelFromJson(json);

  @override
  @JsonKey(name: 'Instytucja')
  final List<InstitutionModel> institutions;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [institutions];
}

@JsonSerializable()
class InstitutionModel extends Institution {
  InstitutionModel({required this.units});

  factory InstitutionModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$InstitutionModelFromJson(json);

  @override
  @JsonKey(name: 'Jednostka')
  final List<UnitModel> units;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [units];
}

@JsonSerializable()
class UnitModel extends Unit {
  UnitModel({required this.sortNumbers});

  factory UnitModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UnitModelFromJson(json);

  @override
  @JsonKey(name: 'NumerRozliczeniowy')
  final List<SortNumberModel> sortNumbers;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [sortNumbers];
}

@JsonSerializable()
class SortNumberModel extends SortNumber {
  SortNumberModel({required this.sortNumber});

  factory SortNumberModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$SortNumberModelFromJson(json);

  @override
  @JsonKey(name: 'NrRozliczeniowy')
  final int sortNumber;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [sortNumber];
}
```

### Data source

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:jaki_to_bank/core/app/files.dart';
import 'package:jaki_to_bank/features/home/data/models/bank_model.dart';
import 'package:jaki_to_bank/features/home/domain/entities/bank.dart';

abstract class BanksDataSource {
  Future<Bank> getBanksList();
}

class BanksDataSourceImpl extends BanksDataSource {
  @override
  Future<Bank> getBanksList() async {
    final String source = Files.banks;

    final String banks = await rootBundle.loadString(source);
    final Map<String, dynamic> banksMap = jsonDecode(banks);

    return BankModel.fromJson(banksMap);
  }
}
```

### Stack trace

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: show the full stack trace error

Comment: Please show us the JSON you're trying to deserialize. The error message seems to indicate that you are trying to cast a map in the JSON to a list.

Comment: @wxker Done, I edited the post with JSON code.

Comment: Why people vote down a perfectly good post is beyond me.  I upvoted just to neutralize it and also show that you have a perfectly good question.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is malformed.

```
{
  "Instytucja": [
    {      <-- missing this
      "TypInstytucji": "bank krajowy",
      "PodtypInstytucji": "bank centralny",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true) on your InstitutionModel (and where ever you have nested classes)
then run:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

for more info check flutter.dev: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json?fbclid=IwAR2sA4lF5zRGneFH4KAqtYLLQXKF6dJqJ8QzmuY-NuEe-hiRPDUx5eNfRa8#generating-code-for-nested-classes